# How to send an Array via URL and extract it in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Here is a script.

It provides some select inputs which allow picking from various types of options. When the submit button is pressed it records the data in `mats` and pushes the `mats` array into an array called `materialsUsed`. Everytime the submit button is clicked a new array is added in `materialsUsed`.

I want to know how to send the `materialsUsed` array through a URL to php to extract the data there and insert it into an array created in PHP.

```
var mats = [name= "", thick= "", size= "", quantity= 0, price= 0];
mats.name = document.getElementById("mat").options[document.getElementById("mat").selectedIndex].value;
mats.thick = document.getElementById("thick").options[document.getElementById("thick").selectedIndex].value;
mats.size = document.getElementById("size").options[document.getElementById("size").selectedIndex].value;
mats.price = parseFloat($('#priceto').val()).toFixed(2);
mats.quantity = parseInt($('#quant').val());
materialsUsed.push(mats);
```

Comment: You're using an array as an object, and not even doing it so well, i must say. Try reading about [the difference between arrays and objects](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-arrays-brackets-braces) in JS.

Comment: Apart from the JavaScript being wrong, passing JSON directly via URL params may lead to trouble if your data is large, as GET/PUT/etc. [are limited in size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers). You really should use POST for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to simply load them as GET values into the URL just set them directly in the URL using location.href. Then simply use $__GET (IE: $__GET['mat']) in PHP to grab values.

```
var baseURL = "http://yourdomain.com";
window.location.href = baseURL + "?mat=" + mats.name + "&thick=" + mats.thick etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to properly prepare your `mats` array and convert `materialsUsed` array into JSON format. Then you can call an ajax function like below, to send it to the php script.

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(materialsUsed);
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "your_script.php",
        data: {data : jsonString}, 

        success: function(){
            alert("Successfully sent the data!");
        }
    });
```

From the `your_script.php` file, you can perform this to extract the array.

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_GET['data']));
```

> Important
>
> When using `GET` method, the amount of the data (length of url) is
>   limited. So, if your `materialUsed` array is too huge, you should use
>   `POST` method instead.

Comment: The OP did say "through the URL" so I'm assuming he would like to use GET not POST.

Comment: also, this uses the jQuery library, OP didn't say anything about jQuery :o XMLHttpRequest ? :p (also the code OP posted, using getElementById seem to suggest that he is in fact NOT using jQuery)

Comment: @hanshenrik Although my answer was without JQuery for the same reason, the OP is using some JQuery mats.price = parseFloat($('#priceto').val()).toFixed(2);
mats.quantity = parseInt($('#quant').val());

Comment: oh, i didn't see that! :o  but why are you using stripslashes? far as i can tell, it will only corrupt the json

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is making an ajax call to your php script providing your js array as its data.
You should listen for the form submission event in your javascript and launch an AJAX call to your PHP script providing your array. You may send your array via the URL (query string) using a GET or in the request body using a POST (that's an option you specify in your AJAX call). Then you would just retrieve your array in your php script an do whatever you want with it.

I suggest you read more on form submission events and [AJAX calls](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) in javaScript.

Quick hint : if you have the possibility to do so, try using jQuery as AJAX is way easier to use with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use associative array, but it's not possible in Javascript as far as I know.

I'd say the best way to do that is creating a object, parsing to json and sending to php. Does't look that hard.